# Image not displaying at Run time

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

The image is not getting displayed at run time.It is displaying in the designer.

> XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="/Assets/logo_108x108.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="400"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="133" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
            <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="DescriptionBrowser"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Navigating="DescriptionBrowser_Navigating" Margin="0,149,0,0"/>            
            <TextBlock x:Name="ErrorBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding LocalizedResourcesFromCommonDll.ErrorGeneral, Source={StaticResource LocalizedCommonStrings}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I tried replacing the Image tag ,but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean something like this. Keep it simple as possible and do not set properties you might not need.

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="/Resources/AnyLogo.png" />
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <WebBrowser />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding TestText}">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TestText}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I tried implementing in the above mentioned way,but still the image is not displaying..

Comment: In you project you have a folder Resources, the picture in there, have you set the property of 'Build Action' to 'Resource'? This should also work: "pack://application:,,,/<yourAssemblyName>;component/Resources/<yourImage.png>"
where <yourAssemblyName> is Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;

Answer (score -1):

I tried the proposed answer and it works for me, with the following remarks:

The `Resources` directory is on the same level as the View, so the Source looks like this: `Source="Resources/img.png"`

Also, on the Properties of the image the `Build Action` is set to `Resource` (by default, but you can still check it)